# Remote Desktop from Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows 7 black screen

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I am experiencing problem when connecting to remote desktop from my Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows 7.
Previously I had no issues connecting to my computers (one Win7 on desktop and other Vista laptop). However I have upgraded laptop from Vista to Win7 and now when I try to connect from Ubuntu most of the time I get black screen using either VNCViewer or default Ubuntu Remote Desktop Viewer or KRDC.

Sometimes it renders me remote desktop but it loads very slowly and is unresponsive.
Interesting thing is that I have no difficulties connecting to desktop pc running Win7 as well.

I tried to follow this guide but with no luck so I concluded issue is with Ubuntu:
https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/277/6/im-getting-a-black-screen-when-i-connect-to-vnc-server

Both Win7 machines are 64bit, newest version of RealVNC server.
My Ubuntu laptop is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, with Intel® Core™ i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4  and IntelHD 4000 GPU.
I thought that problem is with GPU but I am confused now as mentioned above I can connect to other Win7 machine without any difficulties and I was able to connect to the problematic one prior upgrading to Win7 when it was running Win Vista.

I tried to connect to the problematic Win7 laptop from my laptop using Win8 and from other pc running Win and had no difficulties as well.

Have anyone experienced something similar?
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! There is not a specific question asked here. See http://askubuntu.com/tour. This may be a better fit for http://ubuntuforums.org/.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link I will ask there as well. My question is how to solve this issue? Wait for new Ubuntu release or try hardware acceleration etc.? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to follow your question. But have you tried different color depths and using Remmina on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Issue has resolved itself somehow as meantime there were tons on updates for both OS and I guess some of graphics updates solved it